# Consistent value error with unicode comment in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, spyder, python-unicode

I am getting a consistent error in my python code where this error:

> ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

shows everytime I run the code, I really have no idea why this is, as it appears on the first line due to the pyflakes /code analysis features. I have copied and pasted the code into a new script, tried restarting Spyder, and troubleshooted elsewhere with no luck.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can solve this?

Also, this is at the top of my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` could look nice. However, you need to **save** the script using UTF-8 encoding…

Comment: @JosefZ how would I do that? the documentation is pretty unclear.